# PowerApps Canvas App - Want to access a dataverse choice value of a column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I have a form in PowerApps that uses a dataverse table.  The table has columns that are of type 'Choice'.  In the form it shows the labels but I need to be able to access the value of the choice fields to do some calculations?

[image]

How would I reference the currently selected value choices at the time I click the submit button to do a calculation?

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a gallery and the data source is the dataverse table and you only want the text to display, then use this in a text field:

```
ThisItem.SecurityTeamSize.Value
```

In a display form it will be something like:

```
SecurityTeamSize.Value
```